# Appending time series

Tags: r, forecast

If I have 2 time series like this:

```
y <- ts(rnorm(12), start = c(2000, 1), end = c(2000, 12), freq = 12)
z <- ts(rnorm(2), start= c(2001, 1), end = c(2001, 2), freq = 12)
ts.union(y, z)
```

How can I append the 2nd series, but with a single column? The result should be a ts again (not a xts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reassign your `ts` by combining two `ts` and adjusting `start`, `frequency` as follow:

```
ts(c(y,z), start=start(y), frequency=frequency(y))
```

Output:

```
str(df)
Time-Series [1:14] from 2000 to 2001: 0.511 -0.0249 -1.353 0.1526 0.9596 ...
```